# MISRA C:2012 Rule 11.3 A cast shall not be performed between a pointer to object type and a pointer to a different object type

Tags: c, misra, pointer-conversion

```
#define HNULL (void*)0
BYTE  *VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT = HNULL;
WORD  *VRAM_OPTION_I_WORD = HNULL;

void Func1(void)
{
    VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT     = (BYTE *)(PLC_Data + VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT_ADDR);
    VRAM_OPTION_I_WORD    = (WORD *)VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT; //  MISRA Violation 11.3
}
```

The above code gives a MISRA violation.
MISRA C:2012 Rule 11.3 A cast shall not be performed between a pointer to object type and a pointer to a different object type

A common method that I found to solve it was to change the data type of VRAM_OPTION_I_WORD and VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT to void*.

However, the code gives compilation issues when run in the hardware.
Is there a feasible method to solve it ?

Comment: The definition of NULL is given as:
#define NULL ( void * ) 0

Comment: First of all, if you feel the need to add crucial information to your question, don't post it as comments (not that the definition of `NULL` is what most would consider crucial information).

Comment: Secondly, "the code gives compilation issues when run in the hardware" tells me you don't really understand how to develop in C or other compiled languages. A compilation error happens when you build your source, not when running it on the target system. If you're a beginner you shouldn't to embedded development. And you shouldn't be involving the extensive MISRA checks, which are *very* strict and sometimes doesn't allow code that is otherwise valid C.

Comment: I have presented the definition of NULL as giving the definition (#define NULL 0) would cause an another violation. Hence, I made it clear.

Comment: Re-defining NULL isn't allowed in MISRA C, for very good reasons including common sense... so please stop doing that. `#include <stddef.h>` instead.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that. I have changed the name to HNULL:
#define HNULL (void*)0

Comment: Why exactly can't you use standard C `NULL` found in `stddef.h`? Too easy?

Comment: Is the purpose of `HNULL`  just to confuse any reader of your code? Or what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concern here is that it isn't well-defined to access a byte array through a word pointer in C. Alignment and strict pointer aliasing being the reasons why, that's a FAQ and you can read about it here [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Now strict aliasing is mostly just an annoying "defect" in C when it comes to embedded systems and hard-ware related programming, but we can't ignore it, especially not in safety-related software. With a gcc-like compiler it is strongly recommended to disable all strict aliasing optimizations with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. That will remove the hazard but still not sate MISRA C and the code will not be portable either.

Given that a byte in your setting corresponds to a character type, it is actually safe to access any data type through such a pointer, but that's a very special case and does not apply to larger object pointer types.

Avoid using `void*` in high integrity embedded systems - there should ideally be no unknown types or type-generic programming in such a system. So it's not a solution but another problem.

The general work-around is as follows:

- Assuming that you access a chunk of raw memory where no C variables reside, and that the address is aligned, you can access that memory directly from a "word" pointer, without going through another pointer type first. This memory can be regarded as "having no effective type" as the formal C standard puts it.
- Assuming that `PLC_Data` is some integer, then you can do an integer-to-pointer conversion as:
  `(WORD *)(PLC_Data + VRAM_OPTION_I_BIT_ADDR)`. This will put you up against another MISRA rule 11.4, but that one is advisory and far less severe than 11.3.

---

Unrelated to your question, common best practices in C are as follows:

- Do not invent home-brewed type systems. Good engineering == following existing standards. In this case you should be using standard `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` etc from `stdint.h`. Not invent some home-made `BYTE`/`WORD` etc - all you achieve with that is making the code harder to read and more error prone.
- Declaring variable names in ALL CAPS is not a common style. All caps is typically used for macros and constants, and in case of embedded systems, often also for hardware registers. Do not use it for non-const variable names or types.
- Declaring variables outside any function at file scope ("globals") is bad practice and has been debated endlessly elsewhere. And naturally it is not allowed in MISRA C either for those well-known reasons. You have to move the variables inside a function or declare them as `static`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to implement it.